# Why not Property API in hibernate has method in(Criteria subselect)?

Tags: java, hibernate

i have below code snippet in my legacy project

```
  DetachedCriteria subCriteria = DetachedCriteria.forClass(Employee.class);
  subCriteria.setProjection(Projections.distinct(Property.forName ("department.departmentId"))).add(Property.forName("departmentName").eq(departmentName));
  Criteria criteria = getCriteria();
  Property.forName("departmentId").in(subCriteria)
```

My question is  we  have following method **in(DetachedCriteria subselect)** in Property API why not  method **in(Criteria subselect)?** I am sure there shoube be some reason behind it but somehow i did not get this? The reason why i am saying this we should be able to  have another Criteria as subselect instead of DetachedCriteria.

**EDIT:-** How i expects to create subCriteria is below because i have session available  at this point so i dont have any need to use DetachedCriteria

```
  Criteria subCriteria1 =session.createCriteria(Employee.class);   
  subCriteria1.setProjection(Projections.distinct(Property.forName("department.departmentId"))).add(Property.forName("departmentName").eq(departmentName));
 Criteria criteria = getCriteria();
  Property.forName("departmentId").in(subCriteria1)
```

**But subCriteria1 is not acceptable here as only DetachedCriteria is expected as method argument. Why  not Criteria argument is also allowed alongwith DetachedCriteria ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because criterias are bound to a session, detached not.

What should happen if the subcriteria is created with another session? which dialect, interceptor, query substitutions and so on should be used?